# Error: A problem occurred with making the request. DISCORD BOT

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am developing a akinator discord bot (a bot that plays the akinator game). So, it all went good but when I use `node .` the bot comes online, but when I use the command to start the game which is `$aki start`, the bot shows **wait for a second** and then this error shows up in the terminal

`Error: A problem occurred with making the request. Error: A problem occurred with making the request. Request Value: null at rp (C:\Users\ELCOT\Desktop\Aki bot\AkiBot-master\node_modules\aki-api\src\lib\functions\Request.js:25:11) at async module.exports (C:\Users\ELCOT\Desktop\Aki bot\AkiBot-master\node_modules\aki-api\src\functions\start.js:17:18) at async startAki (C:\Users\ELCOT\Desktop\Aki bot\AkiBot-master\functions.js:17:22) TypeError: Cannot read property 'akiMsg' of undefined at Erore404 (C:\Users\ELCOT\Desktop\Aki bot\AkiBot-master\functions.js:340:55) at startAki (C:\Users\ELCOT\Desktop\Aki bot\AkiBot-master\functions.js:47:9)`

Since the error says the issue is with the function.js file, I will share it here, I dont understand the error neither know how to fix it.

This is my function.js file -

````
const {
    RichEmbed
} = require("discord.js");
const {
    region
} = require("./config");
const lang = require("./lang");

let text = lang[region];
let oldCollects = {};


async function startAki(message, akiMsg) {
    try {
        /////////////////// Game Start ///////////////////////////////
        const data = await aki.start(region); // Start Game
        let session = data.session;
        let signature = data.signature;
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        const embed = new RichEmbed()
            .setAuthor(data.question, "https://botlist.imgix.net/3147/c/Akinator-chatbot-medium.jpg")
            .setFooter(`Send By: ${message.author.tag}`, message.guild.iconURl)
            .setTimestamp()
            .addField(`${text.q} 1`, text.options)
            .setThumbnail('https://ar.akinator.com/bundles/elokencesite/images/akitudes_670x1096/defi.png?v95')
            .setColor("#ffffff")


        const emojis = ['1⃣', '2⃣', '3⃣', '4⃣', '5⃣', '↩', '⏹'];
        let x = 0;
        while (x < 7) {
            let emo = emojis[x];
            await akiMsg.react(emo);
            await collectors(message.author, akiMsg, akiMsg.createReactionCollector((reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name == emo && user.id === message.author.id, {
                time: 0
            }), session, signature, 0, null, null, data);
            x++
        }
        await akiMsg.edit({
            embed: embed
        });

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        Erore404(message.author.id)
    }
}

async function collectors(author, akiMsg, collector, session, signature, step, oldWin, enter, data) {

    if (!oldWin) oldWin = null;
    if (!oldCollects[author.id]) {
        oldCollects[author.id] = {
            c: [],
            authorId: author.id,
            date: Date.now(),
            lastid: [],
            q1Question: data.question,
            q1Session: data.session,
            akiMsg: akiMsg,
            wait: 3
        }
    }
    await oldCollects[author.id].c.push(collector);

    collector.on('collect', async r => {
        r.remove(author);
        let answerId;
        if (r.emoji.name == '1⃣') answerId = 0;
        else if (r.emoji.name == '2⃣') answerId = 1;
        else if (r.emoji.name == '3⃣') answerId = 2;
        else if (r.emoji.name == '4⃣') answerId = 3;
        else if (r.emoji.name == '5⃣') answerId = 4;
        else if (r.emoji.name == '⏹') {
            await endGame(author.id, akiMsg);
            return;
        } else if (r.emoji.name == '↩') {
            Back(author, akiMsg, session, signature, answerId, step)
            return;
        } else if (r.emoji.name == '✅') {
            const embed = new RichEmbed()
                .setAuthor(text.correctGuess, "https://botlist.imgix.net/3147/c/Akinator-chatbot-medium.jpg")
                .addField(text.name, oldWin.name, true)
                .addField(text.dis, oldWin.dis, true)
                .addField(text.rank, oldWin.rank, true)
                .setFooter(`Made By: MS6RB#1101`, akiMsg.guild.iconURl)
                .setThumbnail('https://ar.akinator.com/bundles/elokencesite/images/akitudes_670x1096/triomphe.png?v95')
                .setTimestamp()
                .setImage(oldWin.img)
                .setColor("#ffffff")
            akiMsg.edit({
                embed: embed
            });
            akiMsg.clearReactions().then(async m => {
                oldCollects[author.id].c.map(async c => await c.stop());
                delete oldCollects[author.id];
            });
            return;
        } else if (r.emoji.name == '❎') {
            akiMsg.clearReactions()
                .then(async msg => {
                    const emojiss = ['1⃣', '2⃣', '3⃣', '4⃣', '5⃣', '↩', '⏹'];
                    oldCollects[author.id].date = Date.now();
                    oldCollects[author.id].c.map(async c => await c.stop());
                    oldCollects[author.id].c = [];
                    let x = 0;
                    while (x < 7) {
                        let emo = emojiss[x];
                        await msg.react(emo)
                        await collectors(author, akiMsg, akiMsg.createReactionCollector((reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name == emo && user.id === author.id, {
                            time: 0
                        }), session, signature, step)
                        x++
                    }
                })
            return Next(author, akiMsg, session, signature, answerId, step + 1, true);
        }
        Next(author, akiMsg, session, signature, answerId, step, false);

    });

}


async function Next(author, akiMsg, session, signature, answerId, step, enter) {


    /////////////////// Next Answer ///////////////////////////////
    oldCollects[author.id].c.map(async c => await c.stop());
    oldCollects[author.id].c = [];

    const nextInfo = await aki.step(region, session, signature, answerId, step);
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    if (enter == true) oldCollects[author.id].wait--
    if (oldCollects[author.id].wait == 0) {
        enter = false;
        oldCollects[author.id].wait = 3
    }

    if (step >= 72) return Loser(author, akiMsg);

    if (nextInfo.progress >= 90 && enter !== true) {

        const win = await aki.win(region, session, signature, step + 1);

        let guess = win.answers[0];
        const lastIds = oldCollects[author.id].lastid
        let x = lastIds.length;

        if (lastIds.includes(guess.id)) guess = win.answers[x];

        if (guess == undefined) {
            return Loser(author, akiMsg);
        } else {
            oldCollects[author.id].lastid.push(guess.id);
            const embed = new RichEmbed()
                .setAuthor(text.iThinkOf, "https://botlist.imgix.net/3147/c/Akinator-chatbot-medium.jpg")
                .addField(text.name, guess.name, true)
                .addField(text.dis, guess.description, true)
                .addField(text.rank, guess.ranking, true)
                .setFooter(`Send By: ${author.tag}`, akiMsg.guild.iconURl)
                .setThumbnail('https://ar.akinator.com/bundles/elokencesite/images/akitudes_670x1096/confiant.png')
                .setTimestamp()
                .setImage(guess.absolute_picture_path)
                .setColor("#ffffff")
            akiMsg.edit({
                embed: embed
            });
            akiMsg.clearReactions().then(async m => {
                const emojis = ['✅', '❎'];
                oldCollects[author.id].date = Date.now();
                let x = 0;
                while (x < 2) {
                    let emo = emojis[x];
                    await m.react(emo)
                    await collectors(author, akiMsg, akiMsg.createReactionCollector((reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name == emo && user.id === author.id, {
                        time: 0
                    }), session, signature, nextInfo.nextStep, {
                        'name': guess.name,
                        'dis': guess.description,
                        'rank': guess.ranking,
                        'img': guess.absolute_picture_path
                    })
                    x++
                }
            })
        }
    } else {
        const embed = new RichEmbed()
            .setAuthor(nextInfo.nextQuestion, "https://botlist.imgix.net/3147/c/Akinator-chatbot-medium.jpg")
            .setFooter(`Send By: ${author.tag}`, akiMsg.guild.iconURl)
            .setThumbnail(author.avatarURL)
            .setTimestamp()
            .addField(`${text.q} ${nextInfo.currentStep+2}`, text.options)
            .setColor("#ffffff")
        akiMsg.edit({
                embed: embed
            })
            .then(async msg => {
                const emojis = ['1⃣', '2⃣', '3⃣', '4⃣', '5⃣', '↩', '⏹'];
                oldCollects[author.id].date = Date.now();
                let x = 0;
                while (x < 7) {
                    let emo = emojis[x];
                    await collectors(author, akiMsg, akiMsg.createReactionCollector((reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name == emo && user.id === author.id, {
                        time: 0
                    }), session, signature, nextInfo.nextStep, null, enter)
                    x++
                }
            })

    }

}

async function Back(author, akiMsg, session, signature, answerId, step) {

    if (step == 0) return;

    else if (step == 1) {
        oldCollects[author.id].c.map(async c => await c.stop());
        oldCollects[author.id].c = [];

        const embed = new RichEmbed()
            .setAuthor(oldCollects[author.id].q1Question, "https://botlist.imgix.net/3147/c/Akinator-chatbot-medium.jpg")
            .setFooter(`Send By: ${author.tag}`, akiMsg.guild.iconURl)
            .setThumbnail(author.avatarURL)
            .setTimestamp()
            .addField(`${text.q} ${step}`, text.options)
            .setColor("#ffffff")
        akiMsg.edit({
                embed: embed
            })
            .then(async msg => {
                const emojis = ['1⃣', '2⃣', '3⃣', '4⃣', '5⃣', '↩', '⏹'];
                oldCollects[author.id].date = Date.now();
                let x = 0;
                while (x < 7) {
                    let emo = emojis[x];
                    await collectors(author, akiMsg, akiMsg.createReactionCollector((reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name == emo && user.id === author.id, {
                        time: 0
                    }), oldCollects[author.id].q1Session, signature, 0)
                    x++
                }
            })

    } else {
        /////////////////// Back Answer ///////////////////////////////
        oldCollects[author.id].c.map(async c => await c.stop());
        oldCollects[author.id].c = [];

        const previousStep = await aki.back(region, session, signature, answerId, step);
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        const embed = new RichEmbed()
            .setAuthor(previousStep.nextQuestion, "https://botlist.imgix.net/3147/c/Akinator-chatbot-medium.jpg")
            .setFooter(`Send By: ${author.tag}`, akiMsg.guild.iconURl)
            .setThumbnail(author.avatarURL)
            .setTimestamp()
            .addField(`${text.q} ${step}`, text.options)
            .setColor("#ffffff")
        akiMsg.edit({
                embed: embed
            })
            .then(async msg => {
                const emojis = ['1⃣', '2⃣', '3⃣', '4⃣', '5⃣', '↩', '⏹'];
                oldCollects[author.id].date = Date.now();
                let x = 0;
                while (x < 7) {
                    let emo = emojis[x];
                    await collectors(author, akiMsg, akiMsg.createReactionCollector((reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name == emo && user.id === author.id, {
                        time: 0
                    }), session, signature, previousStep.nextStep)
                    x++
                }
            })
    }

}

async function Loser(author, akiMsg) {

    const embed = new RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor(text.giveUp, "https://botlist.imgix.net/3147/c/Akinator-chatbot-medium.jpg")
        .setFooter(`Send By: ${author.tag}`, akiMsg.guild.iconURl)
        .setImage('https://ar.akinator.com/bundles/elokencesite/images/akitudes_670x1096/deception.png')
        .setTimestamp()
        .setColor("#ffffff")
    await akiMsg.edit({
        embed: embed
    });
    akiMsg.clearReactions().then(async m => {
        oldCollects[author.id].c.map(async c => await c.stop());
        delete oldCollects[author.id];
    });
    return;

}

async function endGame(authorId, akiMsg, reason) {

    if (oldCollects[authorId].c) {
        oldCollects[authorId].c.map(async c => await c.stop());
    }
    delete oldCollects[authorId];
    await akiMsg.clearReactions();
    if (reason == 'timeout') await akiMsg.edit(text.gameClosedTimeOut, {
        embed: null
    });
    else await akiMsg.edit(text.gameClosed, {
        embed: null
    })
    return;
}


async function checkTime() {

    for (i in oldCollects) {
        var difference = Date.now() - oldCollects[i].date; // This will give difference in milliseconds
        var resultInMinutes = Math.round(difference / 60000);

        if (resultInMinutes >= 5) {
            try {
                await endGame(oldCollects[i].authorId, oldCollects[i].akiMsg, 'timeout');
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
                Erore404(oldCollects[i].authorId);
            }
        }
    }

}

async function Erore404(authorId) {
    try {
        await endGame(authorId, oldCollects[authorId].akiMsg, 'error');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

module.exports = {
    startAki,
    endGame,
    checkTime,
    oldCollects,
    text
}```


Please help me and consider me as a newb in this feild! So a clear explaination would help a lot! 
I dont know what causes tis error or how to fix it. Hope someone will help! Thanks <3
````

Comment: are you certain ```oldCollects[authorId]``` is valid?   is ```authorId``` a valid index for ```oldCollects```?   in some parts of the code, you have ```oldCollects[i].authorId```

Comment: Im not sure buddy...if you think thats worng, could you suggest what should I replace it with?

Comment: `oldCollects[]` is an array so `oldCollects[authorId]` will return the item at `authorId`. If `authorId` is an user id, the number will be much large and chances are will return `undefined`. Also, I do not see the declaration of `authorId` anywhere. You have also used it as `author.id`. Please check if all your varibales are declared and values are set.